# Updating mongodb field of object type based on category

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document in my MongoDB collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce34ac6a2f25b2448b9b3a3"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5ce34ac6a2f25b2448b9b3a0"),
    "providers" : [ 
        "1689736266", 
        "1598763690", 
        "1528069614", 
        "1831364272", 
        "1548463045", 
        "1245301159", 
        "1386616399", 
        "1790775971", 
        "1629462130", 
        "1992169783"
    ],
    "countByType" : {
        "doctors" : 0,
        "labs" : 0,
        "hospitals" : 0,
        "imagingCenters" : 0
    }
}
```

Categories are doctor, labs, hospital & imagingCenters.
The problem is that for a particular user he doesn't have hospital category, another user may have. So I need to update the countByType field in MongoDB based on categories of user. If the user doesn't contain doctor category, no need to update in MongoDB.
When I tried to update the count, categories which don't exist become null values.

Please see the update query:

```
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
      regUserId, {
          $set:  {
              providers: providernpiId,
              countByType: {
                  "doctors" : counts.doctor,
                    "labs" : counts.lab,
                    "hospitals" : counts.hospital,
                    "imagingCenters" : counts.imagingcenter
              }
           }

      });
```

Now I am getting the output as

```
"countByType" : {
        "doctors" : 6,
        "labs" : null,
        "hospitals" : null,
        "imagingCenters" : null
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
"countByType" : {
        "doctors" : 6,
        "labs" : 1,
        "hospitals" : 0,
        "imagingCenters" : 0
    }
```

If user category contains doctor & lab.

Comment: Why `counts.lab` and not `counts.labs` ?

Comment: @TGrif: counts.lab is the value from elastic search...

Comment: please post `counts` object also.

Comment: @vikash-singh : counts object contains { doctor: 6, other: 4 } . I fetched this data from Elastic Search

Comment: Would not `$ifNull` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pre-check the keys for its existence in `counts` object and if you want to update nested object keys in mongodb then you need to specify the full key path using dot operator, like below :

```js
let setObj = {
  providers: providernpiId
};
let {
  doctor,
  lab,
  hospital,
  imagingcenter
} = counts;
doctor && (setObj["countByType.doctor"] = doctor);
lab && (setObj["countByType.lab"] = lab);
hospital && (setObj["countByType.hospital"] = hospital);
imagingcenter && (setObj["countByType.imagingcenter"] = imagingcenter);
let updateProviderId = await userProviderCollection.update(
  regUserId, {
    $set: setObj
  });
```